# Cookie mysteriously deleted after browser restart

Tags: java, google-chrome, session, cookies, http-headers

I'm attempting to set a cookie which would last for 2 years. However, when I restart the browser, the cookie seems to get deleted.

The behavior seems random, sometimes the cookie is preserved on restart, but on the next restart its gone again.

Full headers returned by my page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 16
x-response-time: 11ms
Set-Cookie: ___auth=853c780cf6cacb177fd641af543c2e23048730aab126c2ee2f93cf0b725f3f30ec425160ea225761bee9bd9c100a1b897031f9194a7564301a9849b6e932440bb299cadabe885ca108973000bf5c183e; 
Expires=Fri, 10 Feb 2017 10:30:53 GMT; Path=/
```

Currently this is being run on `http://localhost:8080`, not yet tested in production. Behavior happens in both chrome and firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your `java` tag. Are you running a Java applet in your webpage? Using a Java server?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Running java as the language on the server.

Comment: Do your response headers actually contain the new line character before `Expires=` as it does in your question? If so, then the browser may be creating a session cookie, which will be deleted on close.

Comment: are you using Cookie API or you're creating these strings and add them to  response using headers API ? :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara No, in the browser its all in one line, I broke it up to be more readable here.

Comment: @Arkantos I'm adding the header to the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/), Expires attribute is deprecated in HTTP 1.1 in favor of `Max-Age`. If you have set some age for a particular cookie, it can be seen as `Max-age` in cookie like below

```
Set-Cookie: UserID=JohnDoe; Max-Age=3600; Version=1
```

But in your response, there's no Max-age set
, so its considered as session cookie and is cleared on browser exit :-)

```
Set-Cookie: ___auth=853c780cf6cacb177fd641af543c2e23048730aab126c2ee2f93cf0b725f3f30ec425160ea225761bee9bd9c100a1b897031f9194a7564301a9849b6e932440bb299cadabe885ca108973000bf5c183e;
```

So create cookies using Cookie API like below and add them to HttpServletResponse in Servlet like this

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("_auth", authString);
cookie.setMaxTime( 63072000 ); // time in seconds

response.addCookie(cookie);
```

With this, it should persist for 2 years :-)

Comment: According to that page, it seems to recommend that `expires` is recommended over `max-age`? "If you care about your cookies functioning properly for a huge percentage of web users (65.66%), don’t persist your cookies “the right way” according to spec (max-age), persist them the way that works (expires)."

Comment: Haha.. I thought you're going to ask that one :-) That post is 5 years old  and the author's intent is to support IE6, IE7, IE8 and other old versions of FF and Chrome. But the current modern browsers are fully standards compliant so you can use `Max-Age` without any issues. so add the `Max-Age` attribute using the `Cookie API` mentioned in my answer because that's is what is considered by modern browsers and I believe that is where your issue is at the moment :) Do you need to support those old browsers as well ?

Comment: I don't think the problem was max-age, but setting it to max-age caused chrome to show all other cookies, and I saw that my framework was resetting the cookie at the end of each request, but without sending the correct expires / max-age. I tracked & fixed the bug, and now everything works. Your comment helped me track this down, so I'm going to accept + award bounty.

Comment: This is what's interesting: My framework reads all cookies at the start of the request, and then adds them back at the end. However, in chrome I see that with the request headers, only the cookie name and value are sent, but not the expires / max-age. Therefore my framework interprets that as 'default expiry time, i.e at end of session', and when it adds the cookies back, it adds it with that default expiry time. Any ideas why chrome doesn't send the expiry time back with the cookie?

Comment: I thinks Expires / Max-Age information is only to tell the browser for how long it should retain that Cookie. It's not sent in the subsequent requests to server, just Cookie name & value are added to  request headers

Comment: That's interesting. I would've thought Netty's developers would know about this.

Comment: One more thing to notice is that `Expires` is a response header and `Max-Age` is an attribute of `Set-Cookie`, another response header but the `Cookie` you get in your framework on server side is only a request header. For full list of headers, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#innerlink_set-cookie)

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)